# why isn't RunAnim a part of roblox's animate string value?

Tags: lua, roblox

```
local function loadAnimation(char)
    local Hum = char:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
    local Animator = Hum:WaitForChild("Animator")

    for _, Track in pairs(Animator:GetPlayingAnimationTracks()) do
        Track:Stop(0)
    end

    local AnimScript = char:WaitForChild("Animate")
    if shared.KeyDown == false then
        AnimScript.run.RunAnim.AnimationId = "rbxassetid://13993857454"
    else
        AnimScript.run.RunAnim.AnimationId = "rbxassetid://13994121294"
    end
    AnimScript.jump.JumpAnim.AnimationId = "rbxassetid://13995055651"
    AnimScript.fall.FallAnim.AnimationId = "rbxassetid://13994774789"
end

local function onPlayerAdded(Player)
    Player.CharacterAppearanceLoaded:Connect(loadAnimation)
end

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(onPlayerAdded)
```

This is from a game I'm making, where it's supposed to change run animations when the player clicks shift to sprint, and yesterday it was working perfectly fine, but somehow today I got the error that RunAnim isn't part of the stringvalue, making all the animation lines obsolete. Why is this?

I checked to see if they've changed some things for the name of the values in roblox, I checked to see if there were any bugs or errors in roblox's servers, but so far I've found none, yet still it claims that my code has the wrong value written in it.

(The script is in server script service, and is not local)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I tried to print the children in the output to see what it thinks I should be writing, and for some reason, I had to type run instead or RunAnim, so in short I had to type in `AnimScript.run.run.AnimationId = "rbxassetid://13993857454"`instead of RunAnim. Very confusing.